# Can i pass variable from Example section into table in behave scenario?

Tags: gherkin, python-behave

Can i do something like this:

```
Response contains requested data
| method | status | url           |
| post   | 200    | <url_variable>|

Examples:
|url_variable|
| test1      |
|test2       |
```

Its a simple example just to show what i want. Is it possible in behave anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i should have just tried what i suggested) it is literally like that, write variable name inside a table in <> quotes. And behave will understand it.